# ActiveX use wrong WorkingDirecotry

Tags: c#, javascript, activex

Probably i'm using a realy bad programming practice but i have to ask some clarification.
I have developed a C# application and then compiled and registere like a COM component.
With javascript i added it to my webpage like ActiveX control.

All is fine except that his Working Directory is set to the Desktop.
My application users and procude some File, i never set the path of that Directory (using the default working directory for an application). 
There is a way to set the Working Directory of the ActiveX (or maybe a Javascript configuration).

This is the small snippet relative to the ActiveX object

```
try {
            var Lib = new ActiveXObject("LIB.MyLib");
            SignLib.Initializer("DEVICE", "");
            alert(SignLib.LibEcho("Success!"));
        } catch (ex) {
            alert("Error: " + ex.message);
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the directory as a method argument? It is not a good idea to change global application current directory just because two internal components needs to exchange some data.

Comment: This will be ,surely, my next fix. I will use some method to set some Path to customize all directory of the application (my app use a lot of file system) so i defintely have to customize it.
But the question (due to knowledge) still persists. 
But again thanks for the hit!!!